# 自動的にループしている？のは何故でしょうか。

Tags: javascript

Javascriptについて質問です。

下記のコードの結果は　"-1 Hold"　なのですが、
①で自動的にループ？のように順番に数字を処理し、値を合計してから②に進んでいるようなのですが、何故でしょうか。

私の予想としては、①②を処理し、アウトプットしてから次の値に進むと思っていました。
　(予想していた結果： "1 Bet", "1 Bet", "-1 Hold", "0 Hold", "-1 Hold"　)

```
   var count = 0;
    function cc(card) {
   ①  switch (card){
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
          count++;
          break;
        case 10:
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "K":
        case "A":
          count--;
          break;
       }   
    ② if (count > 0) {
        return count + " Bet";
      }
      else {
        return count + " Hold";
      }
    }
    
    cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A");    //結果： -1 Hold
```

お助けいただければ幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 結果の-1 Hold というのはどうやってその結果をしりましたか？

Comment: JS Binを使って知りました。
consoleに 「cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A");」と入れると、
結果が「-1 Hold」と出ました。https://jsbin.com/bipafitumi/edit?js,console

Comment: 一行にccの呼び出しを5個まとめて書かないで一行にccの呼び出し1個にして五行にしたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 1個ずつ呼び出すと、こうなりました。(/で区切って書きます)
cc(3); "1 Bet" / cc(7); "1 Bet" / cc("Q"); "0 Hold" / cc(8); "0 Hold" / cc("A");  "-1 Hold"　　・・ということは、つなげて呼び出すと、全部の引数で①までの処理を行ってから②へ進んで最終の値をアウトプットしてくるということなのでしょうか。いまいちこの部分の仕組みがわかっていないようです・・。

Comment: また、五行にして別々に呼び出した場合についてですが、countの値が常に0スタートではなく、前の引数に合わせて更新されていっているようですが、これは「変数の値は常に最新の値に更新されていくという」認識でよいのでしょうか。

Comment: アウトプットというのが何を指しているかこのケースだと若干曖昧なのですが、javascriptって標準出力ないんでしたっけ？誰か他の人、フォローしていただけますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k system さんの回答が適切だと思います。

Suzuranさんのコメント

> JS Binを使って知りました。 consoleに 「cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A");」と入れると、 結果が「-1 Hold」と出ました。

JS Bin のconsole欄に直接入力せずに次のコードで出力すると、「-1 Hold」を得られました。

```
cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); 
console.log(cc("A"));
```

JS Bin の console欄がちょっと特殊だと思うので、console欄に入力ではなく、console.log 命令を使うほうがよいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

#### 自動的にループしているについて

```
cc(3); cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A");
```

を順番に実行して**最後に実行した 文の処理結果が実行結果として表示されている**のです。

例えば

```
var a = 1; var b = 2 ; a + b;
```

は `3` が表示されます。

> (予想していた結果： "1 Bet", "1 Bet", "-1 Hold", "0 Hold", "-1 Hold"　)

のであれば

```
[ cc(3), cc(7) , cc("Q") , cc(8) , cc("A") ]
```

として すべての計算の実行結果を 1つの 配列にすると、
全ての関数の処理結果を まとめて表示できます。

または

```
console.log(cc(3)); console.log(cc(7)); console.log(cc("Q")); console.log(cc(8)); console.log(cc("A"));
```

でも 結果を表示できます。

#### 計算結果が累計されている件

JavaScript は 変数宣言した場所によって その変数スコープ（変数が有効な範囲、見える範囲）が
変わります。

関数の外で宣言しているため、宣言した時に 1回 初期化され
関数が呼び出されるたびにその変数の値を 更新されています。

`count` の値を 0 にしたいのであれば

関数の中に `var count = 0` 宣言を入れるか
関数の先頭で `count = 0` と変数の初期化をするとよいでしょう。

`count` の値を 他の場所で使わないのであれば 関数の中に入れた方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Countの値を常にゼロスタートにしたいならvar count=0;を関数の先頭に移動してください
つなげてよびだしても一個づつ呼び出しても処理順序はかわりません
つなげて呼び出した場合は最後の文の値が全体の値として採用されてるんだと思います

Comment: すいません、最後の文の値が全体の値として採用されてるってのは間違いかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
var count = 0;　を関数内に入れずに cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A"); cc(3);を行うと　"-1 Hold"とアウトプットされたので、最後の値が採用されているのではなく、すべての引数の累計(0+0-1+0-1+1)がアウトプットされているようです。
var count = 0;　を関数内に入れて　cc(7); cc("Q"); cc(8); cc("A"); cc(3);　を行うと　"1 Bet"となったので、こちらは最後の値が採用されているようです。